# I've got problems synching two bots with the same inputs. They work fine with ''position.avg.price'' but won't sync with ''close''

Tags: pine-script

Here I have an example of a normal bot with EXIT positions based on
CLOSE I asked someone to code money management plotting. The 2 bots
respect each other results when I write `strategy.position_avg_price` as
inputs. For some reason when the bots got CLOSE inputs, I can't get them to have the same results. I've got the 2 codes here on how I am trying to match them. Could you guys tell me what I am missing here? They've got almost the same results, but some of the entries/exits differ sometimes.

BOT1:

```
strategy("ETHLONG1h", overlay=false, initial_capital = 100, currency = "USD", pyramiding = 1, calc_on_every_tick=true,
 default_qty_type = strategy.fixed, default_qty_value = 0.02, commission_value = 0.08)
//==========================================================================                     
// ALERT TEXT //SSP
//==========================================================================
alert_tip = "Place this code in the message box while creating/setting alerts"
i_alert_box_code     = input("{{strategy.order.comment}}", "Alert Box code", group="alerts", tooltip=alert_tip)

=========================================================================
// Initial inputs //
Act_RSI_VWAP        = input(true, "RSI VOLUME WEIGHTED AVERAGE PRICE")
RSI_VWAP_length     = input(1,   "RSI-VWAP LENGTH")
RSI_VWAP_overSold   = input(1,   "RSI-VWAP OVERSOLD", type=input.float)
RSI_VWAP_overBought = input(1,   "RSI-VWAP OVERBOUGHT", type=input.float)

// RSI with VWAP as source //
RSI_VWAP = rsi(vwap(close), RSI_VWAP_length)

// Plotting, overlay=false //
r  = plot(RSI_VWAP, color = RSI_VWAP > RSI_VWAP_overBought ? color.red : RSI_VWAP < RSI_VWAP_overSold ? color.lime : color.blue, title="rsi", linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)

h1 = plot(RSI_VWAP_overBought, color = color.gray, style=plot.style_stepline)
h2 = plot(RSI_VWAP_overSold,   color = color.gray, style=plot.style_stepline)

fill(r,h1, color = RSI_VWAP > RSI_VWAP_overBought ? color.red  : na, transp = 60)
fill(r,h2, color = RSI_VWAP < RSI_VWAP_overSold   ? color.lime : na, transp = 60)
  
// ENTRY SIGNALS //

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = (crossover(RSI_VWAP, RSI_VWAP_overSold)), comment="00b033c2_ENTER-LONG_BYBIT_ETH/USDT_00b033c2-ETH1HLONG_1H")
strategy.exit("long SL/TP/TSL", "long", loss = close * 0.018 / syminfo.mintick, trail_points = close *0.008 / syminfo.mintick, trail_offset = close * 0.0001 / syminfo.mintick, comment="00b033c2_EXIT-LONG_BYBIT_ETH/USDT_00b033c2-ETH1HLONG_1H")
```

BOT2:

```
strategy("1hlongETH TRACING", overlay=true, initial_capital = 100, currency = "USD", pyramiding = 1, calc_on_every_tick=true,
 default_qty_type = strategy.fixed, default_qty_value = 0.02, commission_value = 0.08)
                    
// ALERT TEXT and Time stamps//
bt_start      = input(timestamp("01 jan 2015  00:00 +0000"), "Start Date", input.time,  group="backtesting period")
bt_end        = input(timestamp("31 dec 9999  00:00 +0000"), "End Date", input.time,    group="backtesting period")

bt_window = time >= bt_start and time <= bt_end // backtesting window

alert_tip = "Place this code in the message box while creating/setting alerts"
i_alert_box_code     = input("{{strategy.order.comment}}", "Alert Box code", group="alerts", tooltip=alert_tip)

//Trailing,Stoploss,Takeprofit inputs//

i_profit_perc = input(0, "Take Profit (in %)",       group="risk reward", inline="profit") / 100
i_profit_clr  = input(color.green, "",                 group="risk reward", inline="profit")
i_loss_perc   = input(1.8, "StopLoss (in %)",         group="risk reward", inline="loss") / 100
i_loss_clr    = input(color.red, "",                   group="risk reward", inline="loss")
i_trail_act   = input(0.8, "Activate Trail At (in %)", group="risk reward", inline="trailat") / 100
i_trailat_clr   = input(color.yellow, "",                group="risk reward", inline="trailat")
i_trail_off   = input(0.01, "Trail Offset (in %)",   group="risk reward", inline="trailof") / 100
i_trailof_clr   = input(color.fuchsia, "",                 group="risk reward", inline="trailof")

// ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS //
var float buy_en = na
var float buy_sl = na
var float buy_tp = na
var float buy_tl = na
var float trail_act_price = na
var bool trail_activated = false
buy_pos  = strategy.position_size >  0
// ======================================================================
// Initial inputs //
Act_RSI_VWAP        = input(true, "RSI VOLUME WEIGHTED AVERAGE PRICE")
RSI_VWAP_length     = input(1,   "RSI-VWAP LENGTH")
RSI_VWAP_overSold   = input(1,   "RSI-VWAP OVERSOLD", type=input.float)
RSI_VWAP_overBought = input(1,   "RSI-VWAP OVERBOUGHT", type=input.float)

// RSI with VWAP as source //
RSI_VWAP = rsi(vwap(close), RSI_VWAP_length)

// Plotting, overlay=false
// r  = plot(RSI_VWAP, color = RSI_VWAP > RSI_VWAP_overBought ? color.red : RSI_VWAP < RSI_VWAP_overSold ? color.lime : color.blue, title="rsi", linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)

// h1 = plot(RSI_VWAP_overBought, color = color.gray, style=plot.style_stepline)
// h2 = plot(RSI_VWAP_overSold,   color = color.gray, style=plot.style_stepline)

// fill(r,h1, color = RSI_VWAP > RSI_VWAP_overBought ? color.red  : na, transp = 60)
// fill(r,h2, color = RSI_VWAP < RSI_VWAP_overSold   ? color.lime : na, transp = 60)


// ENTRY SIGNALS SL/TP/TSL //
if bt_window
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = (crossover(RSI_VWAP, RSI_VWAP_overSold)), comment="00b033c2_ENTER-LONG_BYBIT_ETH/USDT_00b033c2-LONG5MIN_5M")

if buy_pos
    buy_en := close
    buy_sl := buy_en * (1 - i_loss_perc)
    buy_tp := i_profit_perc > 0.0 ? buy_en * (1 + i_profit_perc) : na
    trail_act_price := buy_en * (1 + i_trail_act)
    trail_off = (buy_en * i_trail_off) / syminfo.mintick
    // if (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick)) > buy_tl
    //     buy_tl := high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick)
    strategy.exit("long SL/TP/TSL", "long", stop=buy_sl, limit=buy_tp, trail_price=trail_act_price, trail_offset=trail_off, comment="00b033c2_EXIT-LONG_BYBIT_ETH/USDT_00b033c2-LONG5MIN_5M")

    if high >= trail_act_price and not trail_activated
        buy_tl := (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick))
        trail_activated := true
    if (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick)) > buy_tl[1] and trail_activated
        buy_tl := (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick))


if strategy.position_size == 0
    buy_tl := na
    trail_activated := false
//==========================================================================
//                 PLOT
//==========================================================================
ben = plot(buy_pos ? buy_en : na, "Buy entry", color.white, 1, plot.style_linebr)
bsl = plot(buy_pos ? buy_sl : na, "Buy Sl", i_loss_clr, 1, plot.style_linebr)
btp = plot(buy_pos ? buy_tp : na, "Buy TP", i_profit_clr, 1, plot.style_linebr)
btl = plot(buy_pos ? buy_tl : na, "Buy Trail", i_trailof_clr, 1, plot.style_linebr)
plot(buy_pos ? trail_act_price : na, "Trail Activate Price", i_trailat_clr, 1, plot.style_linebr)
fill(ben, bsl, color.red, 90)
fill(ben, btp, color.green, 90)
```

I really have to stress here that The BOTS will correctly be synced together if using `strategy.position_avg_price` instead of close, for example:

```
//BOT1//
strategy.exit("long SL/TP/TSL", "long", loss = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.018 / syminfo.mintick, trail_points = strategy.position_avg_price *0.008 / syminfo.mintick, trail_offset = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.0001 / syminfo.mintick, comment="00b033c2_EXIT-LONG_BYBIT_ETH/USDT_00b033c2-ETH1HLONG_1H") 

//BOT2//
if buy_pos
    buy_en := strategy.position_avg_price
    buy_sl := buy_en * (1 - i_loss_perc)
    buy_tp := i_profit_perc > 0.0 ? buy_en * (1 + i_profit_perc) : na
    trail_act_price := buy_en * (1 + i_trail_act)
    trail_off = (buy_en * i_trail_off) / syminfo.mintick
    // if (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick)) > buy_tl
    //     buy_tl := high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick)
    strategy.exit("long SL/TP/TSL", "long", stop=buy_sl, limit=buy_tp, trail_price=trail_act_price, trail_offset=trail_off, comment="00b033c2_EXIT-LONG_BYBIT_ETH/USDT_00b033c2-LONG5MIN_5M")

    if high >= trail_act_price and not trail_activated
        buy_tl := (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick))
        trail_activated := true
    if (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick)) > buy_tl[1] and trail_activated
        buy_tl := (high - (trail_off * syminfo.mintick))
```

The reason I want it on CLOSE is that the bots have great results with multiple live tests, and I don't want to change something that is working well.

Answer (score 0):

> The BOTS will correctly be Synched together if using
> strategy.position_avg_price instead of close

The each strategy instance has its own state (market position and other stuff) that is not synced with other strategy instance. There is no way to sync it. The desicion can be in combine the code of two strategies (BOTs) in single strategy.

Comment: I do not really understand your awnser cause like i mentionned , the 2 codes will be synched correctly when using strategy.position_avg_price as exit ( already tested )
Could you develop on the awnser and explain why is that ? 
Thank you so much for your help Andrey

Comment: Also the 2 strategys are exactly the same. The entrys are always in sync, they are based on a simple rsi crossing vwap. The second script adds different visual plots but thats about it... Only the exit differs for the reason i mentionned.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.  Could you explain more detail what did you mean when said "I want it on CLOSE"?

Comment: Yes sure thanks again for your help Andrey. So there is two kind of options i can write for the exits. I can write : Close OR strategy.position_avg_price. For exemple, for a stop loss  It would look like this :      loss = close  * (number) OR  loss = strategy.position_avg_price * (number).. When those 2 pinescripts codes has the strategy.position.avg_price option, exits are perflectly in sync. With the "close" option, the exits are now different at some places. The 2 strategys entrys are the same its just that the second got the trailing and stoploss plot on the chart.

Comment: So i am trying to understand the difference between the two , seems like the "close" option gets updated with the candles. But why would two pine script codes with the same entrys doesnt get the same exits with this option.. ( inputs are identical everywhere ) thanks again for your time Andrey !!! **i cant find much info regarding those options on the internet**

Comment: Now I've understood your problem. The reason of the difference maybe in fact that there is no any warancy for studies (indi and strats) will be calculated on every RT tick (RT price change). I.e. several tick updates maybe aggregated in one bar update and the first strategy will "see" one CLOSE value but second one will "see" other CLOSE value (+1 RT tick).